# Emulate a 'Chromecast' or allow receiver capability

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm posting my question here because I can't find any suitable answer to it.

I have an Android device that acts as a 'Google TV Board/Box' (linked to TV, network connection, Android OS, ...)

And I have multiple Android devices (smartphones and tablets).

I would like to be able to use the Chromecast application to **cast the screen** of a tablet (for example) **to the 'Google TV board/box'**.

I don't want to use an external Chromecast device as I have all the power needed directly from the board/box.

I heard about the Cheapcast application which emulate a chromecast device but I tested it and since Google change its politics regarding security certificates, I'm not able to make it works.

***So my question is :***

Is there any way to emulate a chromecast on an Android device

**OR**

Is there any way to make this possible wihtout emulating on an Android OS ? Maybe some king of API ?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Some apps for Android will use `RemotePlaybackClient` on the client side, rather than the proprietary Cast SDK. You could create a `MediaRouteProvider` that forwards media requests to the "board/box". Then, any app that uses `RemotePlaybackClient` will be able to work with your device, assuming that the phone or tablet has your `MediaRouteProvider` app on it. [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaRouter) contains sample projects for implementing `MediaRouteProvider` and connecting to it from `RemotePlaybackClient`.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, the official Cast SDKs on the sender sides validate that the Cast device they are talking to is a genuine device, hence you cannot emulate a Cast device if your sender is an using official Cast SDK.

Comment: So, does Google allowed us to create an official receiver ? (Maybe a receiver that must be declared to Google ?)

Comment: Do you mean a cast device or receiver application? If you mean a cast device, the answer is no.